# how implement stk500v2 AMTEL in Android Project

Tags: android, upload, arduino, protocols

I found in github.com the STK500 v1 and V2 protocol in Android, this protocol allows upload HEX files to Arduino boards, in this case my aim is upload the hex file into Arduino Mega.

the protocol are in https://github.com/Prosjekt2-09arduino/STK500-Android and doesn't have documentantion to implements, I read the source code but I don't know how use this code in an Android project, there are a sample but this is for STK500V1.

Actually I am comunicating for serial to Arduino and Android.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developer of this project.

We didn't complete the STK500v2 protocol since the Arduino Uno is using STK500v1.